# How to create command menu item with checkbox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage, vsct

I'm writing a VSPackage and I need to have menu item with checkbox, just like on this sample image below:

[image]

I went through [this msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164699.aspx) regarding *.vsct* files, bud didn't fine any information explaining how to do it. What I have now is standard menu item with icon and text (code sample from MyPackage.vsct file):

```
<Buttons>     
  <Button guid="guidMyPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidMyPackage" type="Button">
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="myPackageBitmap" />
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>DontCache</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>FixMenuController</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>MyPackage</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>      
</Buttons>
```

I need this additional checkbox. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The properties like `Checked`, `Visible`, `Enabled` or `Supported` can´t be defined via the `VSCT` file. You need a command handler that controls the command´s state. I´ve created a base class that wraps the creation of the `OleMenuCommand` instance and handles the command´s `BeforeQueryStatus` event. This is a slimmed version of my implementation, but it will give you an idea how to solve it...

```
internal abstract class CommandHandler : IDisposable
{
    private readonly OleMenuCommand command;

    protected CommandHandler(Guid group, int id)
    {
        var commandid = CommandID(group, id);
        this.command = new OleMenuCommand(this.Invoke, commandId);
        this.command.BeforeQueryStatus += this.OnBeforeQueryStatus;
    }

    protected virtual void OnExecute() { } 

    protected virtual void OnQueryStatus(QueryStatusEventArgs e) { }

    private void Invoke(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnExecute();
    }

    private void OnBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleMenuCommand command;
        if ((command = sender as OleMenuCommand) != null)
        {
            var e = new QueryCommandEventArgs
            {
                Checked = command.Checked,
            }

            this.OnQueryStatus(e);

            command.Checked = e.Checked;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.command.BeforeQueryStatus -= this.OnBeforeQueryStatus;
    }
}

public class QueryCommandEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

The `CommandHandler` class allows to control the state of any menu command. Just derive new handler implementations from it and override the `OnExecute` and `OnQueryStatus` methods, like...

```
internal sealed class MyCommand : CommandHandler
{
    private bool checked;

    public MyCommand() : base(GuidCmdSet, MyCommandId) { }

    protected override void OnExecute()
    {
        this.checked = !this.checked; // toggle checked state
    }

    protected override void OnQueryStatus(QueryStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Checked = this.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I didn't notice these properties exposed by `OleMenuCommand`. Thanks. But still, this checkbox looks differently than this one presented on the screenshot in my question. Maybe these from screenshot are just separate menu items toggled by theirs visibility state... ([like shown here](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/05/23/vs-2010-package-development-chapter-2-commands-menus-and-toolbars.aspx))? And second difference - when I click on item, it closes (disappears, which is normally correct behavior). Do you know how to keep it constantly opened (on top) during clicking?

Comment: Hm; I would say that the checkboxes do look the same as in the screenshot; unfortunately I´ve no clue how to prevent the menu from closing when an item is clicked.