# Visual studio Toolbars menu items like menu item in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does anyone knows how to implement menu item with toggle icon similar to visual studio Toolbar menu. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jack for your reply. Solution would be adding two menu items(with and without checkbox icon) and toggle 
the visibility state of both menu items in BeforeQueryStatus event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class to handles the command´s BeforeQueryStatus event and use the checkbox in your side.

The simliar issue has been asked here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f3acc18c-b176-4f06-a8d1-cccff3d4bf7f/how-to-disable-and-enable-menu-commands-in-vspackage?forum=vsx

[How to create command menu item with checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033517/how-to-create-command-menu-item-with-checkbox)